# How to create Control array at design time for ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to Create Control array at Design Time for ListBox in Windows C# ?

Any help/ideas are appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: @alexm: I think OP means, we can Repeat(copy paste) similar controls during design time and give unique Names to each. How can this be done using an Array, at Design time.

Comment: @Alexm : Group of Controls. Example : I have a Tab control which contains 8 Tabs and for each Tab i want a ListBox so i want to Create Group of ListBox which i can access from their Index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Control Arrays are gone in Net Framework, but instead you can create a collection of Listbox. This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289500%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) will guide you through.

[other link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/45666-control-arrays-in-c%23/)